# Are BigQuery DML updates better than a join?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table in BigQuery where I need to update a specific column's values every day.  I will have a table generated every day with the new column values and a key I can use to join to the partitioned table.  My question is: would it be better to do a left outer join with the partitioned table to the table with the new values, or would an update DML statement be better?

I have not found anything that says one way or the other - it appears both methods would cost the same.  The one problem with the join is that I would have to destroy and recreate my partitioned table every day, while an update statement would not do that.  Both are doing a full table scan though...

Comment: DML is more clean solution while in some cases people get confused with syntax thus going with old school approach using select statement with output going to destination table usually simpler syntax wise (i see this at least based on questions in SO)

Comment: Tend to agree with Mikhail here. DML also has a few limitations.